# collision detection, in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am new to the world of `libgdx` and the world of game programming in general. I want to create a game, but not any game. I have created some basic game like **breaks**, and **pong**. But I still cant go any further, I *google* for good articles, but I always have problems with collision, especially between entities! I want to create a game with slopes like **sonic**.

Comment: Some reading: http://www.a-coding.com/2010/10/predictive-collision-detection.html http://www.vobarian.com/collisions/

Comment: Also, if you scroll down and look on the right at related questions, I see a lot of questions about collision detection. Tried reading them?

Answer (score 5):

Why not use Box2D (libGDX extension) ? It's perfect for platformers.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Although it is not always appropriate, Box2D can often be a good solution for those unwilling to 'roll their own' collision detection.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know how to create rectangles. I assume that you know about rectangles.
if you want to check collision of two rectangles you can do as follows:

```
Rectangle a = new Rectangle(), b = new Rectangle();
```

in constructor set rectangles

```
a.setRectangle(yourX, yourY, yourWidth, yourHeight);
b.setRectangle(yourX, yourY, yourWidth, yourHeight);
```

in render check collision like this:

```
if(a.overlaps(b))
{
  //do your work
}
```

Comment: first, thanks for your answer,and yes, i know about rectangles, but they are useless in my opinion for map collisions and specialy on the TiledMap class that libgdx provide, and i don't think that i can use them for slopes, thank you again !!

Comment: for collision in tile map you can refer this link   http://www.creatiosoft.com/how-to-detect-collision-in-tilemap

Answer (score 3):

U can use OverlapTester class given in SuperJumper Project by LibGdx

Answer (score 3):

Create Your bounds using rectangle class in Libgdx and test them using **Intersector** class.

This class has many function to test overlapping of rectangles, circles etc..

Comment: thank you very much, i have read only the prototypes and i found that its very useful , i will google it to learn more, but please , let me ask you one more question, can i use it for map collision??, if yes , then how, and thank you once more :)

Comment: @Vikalp Jain what if my sprites arent rectangular, how would I do collisions ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use box2d if you know the basics.
if you know how to use a rectangle, sprite batch, camera etc. Then you should proceed to Box2d if you don't just take some good tutorial and try to make the application without any extension.this will make your concept clear and you will easily able to grasp the logic behind the game.